# Binding.pry failing in shared example block?

Tags: ruby, debugging, rspec, rubygems, pry

I have a project where placing a binding.pry will work when running RSpec tests except in classes where we use a shared example. We have it set up to where there are two blocks, one in the class itself that handles errors, and another in the shared example. The structure is like this (Sorry I can't get more specific, there is a lot of code):

Class -> (Code surrounded by block)

```
require 'pry'
def class(param, param)
  ClassThatTakesBlock.handle() do |_some_event|
    rest of class's code...
    binding.pry # Fails dramatically when running RSpec
    ...
    end
  end
end
```

Shared example -> (Code surrounded by block)

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'some class' do |optional_param1, optional_param2|
  subject { class(param: param_hash, param: param) }
  ...
  end
end
```

Class spec ->

```
RSpec.describe 'directory/class' do
  it_behaves_like 'some class', false do
  ...
  end
end
```

The problem is when I require 'pry' and try to place a binding.pry, and run a spec that goes past that binding.pry, the spec will throw a bunch of errors with something like
`Failure/Error: subject { class(param: param_hash, param: param) }` (The subject line of shared example)

```
expected: ("AWS param in class")
              got: ("DISABLE_PRY")
        Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
```

`Shared Example Group: "some class" called from ./file_directory/path/class_spec.rb:40`

Along with a big wall of what looks like params, bundler paths, rvm flags, etc.

Is there something special I need to do to get binding.pry working in a shared example? Or is there another way to place a debugger within the code? I can't even get print statements to surface when I run RSpec and I can't debug my specs.

Comment: `binding.pry` usually works fine in a shared example. I don't expect that's the problem here. My guess is that the crazy error is caused by defining a method called `class`, which conflicts with the reserved word `class`? That's a very weird thing to do...

Answer (score 1):

the method name `class` is causing the issue, because the keyword `class` is reserved in ruby. My suggestion is to name it klass.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue I had was incorrect stubbing. Adding

```
allow(ENV).to receive(:[])
```

fixed it, but I also think stubbing stdout was also causing issues.